# should a singleton use self or shared instance inside the methods

Tags: ios, objective-c, singleton

inside the singleton methods how should I use a singleton:

like:

```
     [self doMethod];
```

or:

```
    [[SingletonClass sharedSingleton] doMethod];
```

?

Comment: If it's a singleton, aren't those the same?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can think of no reason to do it the second way. That way is longer, slower and more brittle -- and there's no upside to it. Just use `self` unless you have a really compelling reason to do otherwise. Singletons are essentially just normal objects.

Comment: The only purpose for the second technique is in class methods (the `+` methods). But for instance methods (the `-` methods), `self` is definitely preferable.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to minimize the number of calls made by the client, so I recommend you have a convenience class method on your singleton that sends the instance method to the singleton.

Comment: in your answer, who's the client?

Comment: @Flores Whoever is initiating the call to the method on the singleton

Comment: I think there is one less call if you have: `[[SingletonClass sharedSingleton] doMethod];` than if you have `[SingletonClass classMethod]` and later in the class `[[SingletonClass sharedSingleton] doMethod];`

Comment: @FloresRobles It depends on how many times you want to call the method.  You want to be sure that you make only one method call in the calling code every time the method is called from somewhere.  My approach makes from cleaner, simpler code when the method is called sever times.